# Change primary key on manytomany field Django

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to change primary key of many to many field from default to uuid?

Table is already populated. What is the best way for migration?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a migration that executes raw queries, add a new field to the table in the middle then generate the new UUID.

After that, another set of queries to drop the constraints on ID, add the new constraints to the new UUID field, and lastly drop the old ID field.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/migration-operations/#runsql